# Looking for a Logic Solution to Build Dynamic Filepath in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, dynamic, filepath

I have a file structure which is being built in the following manner.

**1) Each user is provided an ID in MySQL database.**

**2) When user uploads an image from iphone the image is placed in the following directory:**

```
`../images/[USER_ID]/[IMAGE_NUMBER].jpg`
```

**3) In the path noted above, `[IMAGE_NUMBER]` is generated based upon the submission value. So the first image uploaded will be titled `1.jpg`, the second as `2.jpg` etc…**

So to build a sample directory for the purposes of this question the structure could look something like this:

```
../images-->
    ../10/1.jpg
    ../10/2.jpg
    ../10/3.jpg
    ../11/4.jpg
    ../11/5.jpg
    ../10/6.jpg
    ../11/7.jpg
```

So in this case, `User #10` uploaded 3 images, then logged out.  Along comes `User #11` and she uploads 2 images before logging out.  And finally, `User #10` logs back in and uploads another image.

Okay now that we have the summary of out the directories are being generated and images are dynamically input, let me get to the ultimate question.  I would like to be able to display thumbnails of all the images on a view in the iphone when a user clicks a button that we will call `btnRefresh`

Here is the method that is associated with `btnRefresh`:

```
-(IBAction)btnRefreshTapped
{
[self refreshStream];
}
-(void)refreshStream {
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         @"stream",@"command",
                                         nil]
                           onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
                               [self showStream:[json objectForKey:@"result"]];
                           }];
}
```

As you can see this is referencing the `API sharedInstance` here is that method:

```
+(API*)sharedInstance
{
static API *sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost]];
});
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

and finally we come full circle to the `URLWithString` value:

```
-(NSURL*)urlForImageWithId:(NSNumber*)IdPhoto isThumb:(BOOL)isThumb {

int IdValue = [[user objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];

NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@upload/%d/%@%@.jpg",
                       kAPIHost, kAPIPath, IdValue, IdPhoto, (isThumb)?@"-thumb":@""
                       ];
return [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}
```

So, herein lies my problem.  As this is currently being defined I can only see the images of the user that is logged into the app when they click `btnRefresh`.  The other image locations show up as greyed out images due to the broken URLs.  So, how can I redefine `IdValue` to cycle through available folders and pull the associated images for display?

I know this is a complex problem so thank you to putting some brainpower into a solution.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to search for image with name in all directories. I dont know why are u assuming that it will be in "user" object. Please clarify why you need to access "user" for in this code?

Comment: @GauravGoyal initially I used this to pull the directory name.  I know that it is wrong, but I used it to show how the URL needs to be built.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it what you asking but you can get all files from the directory via this code:

```
NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:YourURL
                               includingPropertiesForKeys:@[] // <-Add key/s if needed
     options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension == 'jpg'"];
for (NSURL *fileURL in [contents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate])
{
    // Enumerate each .jpg file in directory
}
```

You can specify images directory and you should be able to find the images and get url to that.

The other way is recursively enumerate files in directory, it's more powerful and it can be amended to your requirement:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:YOURURL
                                      includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey] // <-Add more key if needed
                                                         options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                    errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
}];

NSMutableArray *mutableFileURLs = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSURL *fileURL in enumerator) {
    NSString *filename;
    [fileURL getResourceValue:&filename forKey:NSURLNameKey error:nil];

    NSNumber *isDirectory;
    [fileURL getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:nil];

    if (![isDirectory boolValue]) {
        [mutableFileURLs addObject:fileURL];
    }
}
```

Hope one of those will be usefull for you.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I am looking into this now.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying what Greg just answered so that you don't have to iterate the array.

```
NSArray *paths = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:YourURL
                            includingPropertiesForKeys:@[]
                                               options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                         [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"self ENDSWITH '/filename.jpg'"]];

NSArray *filteredArray = [paths filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if ([newarray lastObject]) {
    //you have your path here
}
```

filename.jpg is the IdPhoto.jpg in your code. This code with work because of the type of data you have. I have included "/" in filename.jpg so that there are no issues in detecting 110.jpg vs 10.jpg.